NSwag WrapResponseMethods parameter format
When adding an OpenAPI service reference I can't get the WrapResponseMethods to work. From https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/blob/6b49eefa4048cecfd41ba0d7484bd1f25543d22d/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/CodeGeneration/OpenApiToCSharpCommandBase.cs#L112 it looks like it should be "ControllerName.MethodName", but the below doesn't work:
/WrapResponses:true /WrapResponseMethods:["Finance.Products", "Finance.GetAllProducts"]
I've tried different combinations of quotes and casing etc but still no joy. Without specifying WrapResponseMethods it does wrap every method.
OpenAPI json:
"/v0.1/Finance/Products": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "Finance"
    ],
    "operationId": "GetAllProducts"

